# Laravel 4: Generating Views with PHP's mkdir() Function

Tags: php, laravel-4, directory-structure

I would like site administrators to have the ability to create view directories through the user interface.

Here's the breakdown:

- My system consists of about 30 different forms (for example, one form allows employees to add monthly statistics for their department).
- Each form has its own directory within the app/views directory.
- An admin has the option to create a new form (form_id and form_name) in the database
- When the new form is created, a new directory in the app/views folder is generated using PHP mkdir()

The problem is that in order to do this I obviously need to chmod 777 my app/views directory. Is there a better way to generate this new directory through Laravel? Should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: `chmod` of 777 doesn't sound like a good idea - are you on shared hosting? Unless you have `suexec` or something, that will technically make your files readable and writable by other customers on the same box.

Comment: The server is internal and only used our company but I still don't feel comfortable having a 777 directory.

Comment: If your company is the only user, it's not so bad. Of course it is best for files to be read-only from the web server user's perspective unless they need to be written to, but in some envs that's not possible.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose all of the sub-directories where the view files will actually live will be 755 anyway.

Comment: Have you tried set chown to www-data (or other - depends on the env)?

Comment: I still want to be able to add files to that directory myself. Chown www-data strips me of that ability right?

Comment: When you say "myself", what do you mean? As the web server user via something in PHP? Or your *nix account user?

Comment: Correct as the web server user.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the storage folder or something already writable.

Here's how you create a folder

```
$result = File::makeDirectory(app_path().'/path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

source
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147